# Updating metadata with a single transaction

Tags: polkadot-js

Is it possible to update all metadata for all chains on Polkadot.js by signing only one transaction?

Comment: Clients get chain's metadata from their runtimes, I don't know if I follow your question.
https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/metadata/

Comment: The root of this question stems from it being cumbersome to sign transactions for every chain while interacting on Polksdot.js.  For background, I am part of a validation company, and being current on changes to statuses of projects through their various testnet stages is important.  This requires me to sign many metadata updates while I go through project lists.  This process gets repeated over again quite frequently.  From my POV, and I am not a developer so forgive me if this is an improbable feat, but it would streamline my workload if I could sign one Tx for updating all metadata.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no". For each chain the apps UI would need to connect to, get the metadata and then check against the extension.

The apps UI has quite a number of chains... 234 by my count. Due to this, it only does the actual connected chain.